# How to make Adobe Air audio work?

Tags: 64-bit, adobe-air

Does anyone have any idea on how to make Air Adobe work on a 64-bit Ubuntu?  If I try to install the .bin version from the Adobe site, the application using Adobe Air works fine but there's no sound!

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your title so that you mention the problem is with audio support.

Comment: Its not the sound plugins for me as I have them installed

Answer (score 1):

Here it talks about installing Adobe Air (a 32-bit application) on Ubuntu 64-bit,
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/521/cpsid_52132.html

If sound does not work, then most probably a dependency (probably an application library related to sound) has not been installed. 
You would use `ldd` and the name of the Adobe Air executable to see what libraries are missing.

However, the proper way to deal with this issue would be to ask for help at Adobe at the article 
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/521/cpsid_52132.html

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advice and read the article and now I'm just curious as to how can I do this:"You would use ldd and the name of the Adobe Air executable to see what libraries are missing."?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have the 32-bit asound libraries installed. From the command line, simply do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```

After that, your AIR applications will be able to play sounds.